# Angular Js Binding

Tags: angularjs, spring

Angular js have functions for to load vaccine Mater details on the page load. It will be displayed in the dropdown.

```
{
    "code": 0,
    "message": "Total 3 records found",
    "result": [{
        "vaccinationId": 1,
        "vaccinationName": "vacc 1",
        "vaccinationNameAr": null
    }, {
        "vaccinationId": 2,
        "vaccinationName": "vacc 2",
        "vaccinationNameAr": null
    }, {
        "vaccinationId": 3,
        "vaccinationName": "vacc 3",
        "vaccinationNameAr": null
    }]
}
```

On search click I had to fetch values from another table, this table will have foreign key reference to vaccination Id.

```
{
    "code": null,
    "message": "Page is searched successfully",
    "result": {
        "totalRecords": 2,
        "searchList": [{
            "jobVaccinationPK": {

                "vaccinationId": 1,
                "screeningTypeId": 2,
                "jobCategoryId": 1
            },
            "jobVaccinationPK": {
                "vaccinationId": 1,
                "screeningTypeId": 2,
                "jobCategoryId": 1
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

If json response is like this, Can I get map vaccination Id in UI, with already loaded vaccination master data ?
or DO I need to fetch the master data again with the second json?

Comment: you can save the vaccination id in a scope variable and use it whole making the second call

Answer (score 0):

You can have a variable let's say `selectedVaccinationId`.

You will have to handle click event on dropdown options and based on the option clicked, assign the vaccinationId to the `selectedVaccinationId` variable. Use this variable's value to fetch the data from second table.